# Reactjs.NET - Props is undefined and stuck on why?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui, reactjs.net

So i'm still finding my feet with reactjs.net + asp.net core. I've imported latest version (v1) of material-ui.com into the mix. I am trying to combine the two but having issues with classes/props composition.

The code below is verbatim of what i've been told i need and found via hours of searching online. Yet, `this.props.classes` continue to throw `undefined` errors.

Is there a step i'm missing?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';



const homeStyles = {
  root: {
    height: 200 ,
    flexGrow: 1,
  },

  grow: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },

  menuButton: {
    marginLeft: -12,
    marginRight: 20,
  },
};


export class Home extends React.Component {


    displayName = Home.name

    constructor(props) { 
        super(props);
        console.log("Props: " + props != null);
    }

  render() {

      const { classes } = this.props;

      return (
         <div>
            <div className={classes.root}>
            <AppBar position="static">
            <Toolbar>
              <IconButton style={classes.menuButton} color="inherit" aria-label="Menu">
                <MenuIcon />
              </IconButton>
              <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" style={classes.grow}>Undefined? {(this.props == undefined).toString()}</Typography>
              <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
            </Toolbar>
          </AppBar>
          </div>
        </div>
    );

   }
}

Home.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(homeStyles)(Home)
```

Comment: What *specifically* is undefined? "props / classes" is imprecise. What *specifically* are you importing in the consumer of this component?

Comment: const { classes } = this.props;

In order to use {classes.menuButton} this.props needs to initialize. However throughout all the lifecycle this.props is undefined.

Comment: Hi @ScottBarnes, I have not used material-ui, but looking at its doco it seems you are consuming correctly its styles. Could you include the code that is consuming `Home`?